# install4j - Updating Program Group Name

Tags: install4j

I give the option of going back to the installation components screen, so that the user selects a different installation component if he wants to.

But, how do I update the Program Group Name.

I see a class CreateProgramGroupAction, and  a method updateProgramGroupName(Context arg0) inside that. But how do i use it? I am not finding any relevant documentation on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the "Properties" tab after selecting the "Create program group" action. There's a property  "Program group name" and by default it is set to `${installer:sys.programGroup.name}`. With the following call:

```
context.setVariable("sys.programGroup.name", "your value");
```

you can override the value that is set by the "Create program group" screen.

Comment: That worked, Ingo. Thanks a lot! Except for the fact that (after a little digging into the library) it is "sys.programGroup.name". Thank you, once again! I was trying many other things than this simple step.

Comment: Indeed, that was the variable name in 4.x, in 5.x it is sys.programGroupName.

Answer (score 0):

To add to this, make sure that you don't specify any values in properties tab in "Create Programs Action", if you are dealing with "Program Group Name" programatically.