# Install4j - Is there a way to have the Program Group match the Media Installation Directory value?

Tags: java, install4j

Specifically I have multiple Media files, and I would like to customize the Program Group Name to match the media files Installation Directory. I know you can make it match the Media File's name, but this is problematic as I have a 32 and 64 bit version of the same media file, making it very hard to read what's what in the Media Configuration screen. In other words, there are two of each media file in my screen.

If I could just use the Installation Directory value that I overrode, or some other way of getting a value specific in the Media File, that would be great!

**Update:** I also just tried to to use the following pre-activation script which did not seem to work:

```
if(context.getMediaFileId().equals("mediaFileID#1"))
    context.setVariable("sys.programGroup.name", "MyCustomGroupName");
else if(context.getMediaFileId().equals("mediaFileID#2"))
    context.setVariable("sys.programGroup.name", "MyCustomGroupName2");
else 
    context.setVariable("sys.programGroup.name", "Not even this works...");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was the variable name. I used the older name as indicated by Ingo in the following StackOverFlow response: [install4j - Updating Program Group Name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9573133/install4j-updating-program-group-name) where it should now be sys.programGroupName and not sys.programGroup.name